# SideWaffle - create your own template set to share

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, sidewaffle

I am looking to create a set of templates to use with my Dev team, but I don't want them to be available to everyone on the GitHub project.

How can I create my own subset of templates to share with my team without having to send files or copy paste or anything else?  I want the same level of version control that I would get if using GitHub.

Comment: How does a private fork allow sharing from inside of VS2012/13 with SideWaffle?

Comment: Did you get this working? I'd love to hear what you used this for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the exact same model as SideWaffle Template Pack (sidewaffle.com) uses for your own templates. Download the Visual Studio SDK from Microsoft and then create a new "VSIX Project". All you then need to do is to ad the NuGet package "TemplateBuilder" (http://www.nuget.org/packages/TemplateBuilder/1.0.3.21-beta)

See the SideWAffle wiki on [How to create your own template pack](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-template-pack).